# DotNetZip: How to extract files, but ignoring the path in the zipfile?

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

Trying to extract files to a given folder ignoring the path in the zipfile but there doesn't seem to be a way.

This seems a fairly basic requirement given all the other good stuff implemented in there.

What am i missing ?

code is -

```
using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zf = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
{
    zf.ExtractAll(appPath);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution but I would like to only remove the first step of all the files contents... eg /my solution/file/file1.txt becomes /file/file1.txt. Any resource for this?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202267/how-to-zip-only-files-and-not-the-full-path-hierarchy-with-dotnetzip-in-powershe @atwellpub

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to remove the directory part of the filename just prior to unzipping...

```
using (var zf = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
{
    zf.ToList().ForEach(entry =>
    {
        entry.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(entry.FileName);
        entry.Extract(appPath);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why `zf.ToList().ForEach(entry => {...})` instead of `foreach (var entry in zf.Entries){}`? Is there some difference?

Comment: What about `zf.FlattenFoldersOnExtract = true` ?

Answer (score 25):

While you can't specify it for a specific call to `Extract()` or `ExtractAll()`, the `ZipFile` class has a `FlattenFoldersOnExtract` field. When set to true, it flattens all the extracted files into one folder:

```
var flattenFoldersOnExtract = zip.FlattenFoldersOnExtract;
zip.FlattenFoldersOnExtract = true;
zip.ExtractAll();
zip.FlattenFoldersOnExtract = flattenFoldersOnExtract;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ([DontNetZip doc](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/4970c6e8-c169-3ecc-b5f2-8ba9b354c51d.htm)). The other answer is a workaround: it renames the file inside the zip before extracting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload that takes a stream as a parameter. In this way you have full control of path where the files will be extracted to.

Example:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(ZipPath))
{
     foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
     {
        string newPath = Path.Combine(FolderToExtractTo, e.FileName);

        if (e.IsDirectory)
        {
           Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        }
        else
        {
          using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create))
             e.Extract(stream);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I kept getting "An item with the same key has already been added" errors with the one marked as answer (maybe an error on my part, but anyway).

Answer (score 1):

That will fail if there are 2 files with equal filenames. For example
files\additionalfiles\file1.txt
temp\file1.txt

First file will be renamed to file1.txt in the zip file and when the second file is trying to be renamed an exception is thrown saying that an item with the same key already exists