# How to zip only files and not the full path hierarchy with DotNetZip in powershell?

Tags: powershell, dotnetzip

I'm trying to zip up log using DotNetZip and powershell.  The files are in C:\user\temp\logs When I loop through the logs in the directory and add them to the zip file, I end up with the folder hierarchy and the log files when I only want the log files.

So the zip ends up containing:

```
-user
  └temp  
    └logs
       └log1.log
        log2.log
        log3.log
```

When I want the zip file to contain is:

```
log1.log
log2.log
log3.log
```

Here is the script I'm running to test with:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\\\User\\bin\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
$zipfile = new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile("C:\user\temp\logs\TestZIP.zip");

$directory = "C:\user\temp\logs\"
$children = get-childitem -path $directory
foreach ($o in $children)
{
   if($o.Name.EndsWith(".log")){
      $e = $zipfile.AddFile($o.FullName)
   }
}
$zipfile.Save()
$zipfile.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an [AddFile](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/202e1fb5-8891-888f-8e91-1340f7cd80c9.htm) where you can override the filename in the archive:

```
public ZipEntry AddFile(
    string fileName,
    string directoryPathInArchive
)
```

> *fileName (**String**)*
>
> The name of the file to add. The name of the file may be a relative
>   path or a fully-qualified path.
>
> *directoryPathInArchive (**String**)*
>
> Specifies a directory path to use to override any path in the fileName.
>   This path may, or may not, correspond
>   to a real directory in the current
>   filesystem. If the files within the
>   zip are later extracted, this is the
>   path used for the extracted file.
>   Passing null (Nothing in VB) will use
>   the path on the fileName, if any.
>   **Passing the empty string ("") will
>   insert the item at the root path
>   within the archive.**

Try this:

```
 $e = $zipfile.AddFile($o.FullName, $o.Name)
```

It is also possible that this does what you want:

```
 $e = $zipfile.AddFile($o.FullName, "")
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted `$e = $zipfile.AddFile($o.FullName, "")
`

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think this should work.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\\\User\\bin\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
$zipfile = new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile("C:\user\temp\logs\TestZIP.zip");

    $directory = "C:\user\temp\logs\"
    set-location $directory
    $children = get-childitem *.log
    foreach ($o in $children)
    {
        $e = $zipfile.AddFile($o.Name)
       }
    }
    $zipfile.Save()
    $zipfile.Dispose()
```

Comment: One reason this would not work is that Set-Location does not change the current directory for the process.  Any paths that you pass to methods on objects are relative to the process' current directory.  This seems to be a very common pitfall with PowerShell.