# Save ZipArchive to file

Tags: c#, stream, c#-ziparchive

In my application I have a class manipulating with zip  archive using `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`.
Now I want to save the entries of the archive to file. How can I do that? I know I can associate a `Stream` with archive but in my case the archive creates w/o streams and I can't change the code:

```
var archive = ZipFile.Open(fileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
// add entries
// how can I save it to file now?
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please check this answer:
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12670368/6340841)

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers but that not what I need. As I said I use `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` and I can't change it for another library.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you explain more about your use case?

Comment: Sure, but what exactly isn't clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already 'saving it to a file', the one indicated by `fileName`.

To make sure everything is written and flushed, use a `using` :

```
using (var archive = ZipFile.Open(fileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
   // add entries
   ....

}  // here it is saved and closed
```

Comment: Thanks, @Henk Holterman, you're right, I've noticed that this code creates a file. Unfortunately it's empty although I add several `ZipArchiveEntry` items.

Comment: It's ok, I've found a way to do that. In my code I didn't use `using` so it looks that file just remained opened. I've added `archive.Dispose()` in my class destructor and now it work fine, archive created as expected.