# how to remove path dotnetzip c#

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

my project is framework 4.0 so i use DotNetZip.
i have a code to save zip to E:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
    zip.AddFile(CGlobalVar.CurrentMissionFolder + "\\OutputTxt\\" + satuan.sName + "\\child.txt");
    zip.AddFile(CGlobalVar.CurrentMissionFolder + "\\OutputTxt\\" + satuan.sName + "\\gps_default.txt");
    zip.AddFile(CGlobalVar.CurrentMissionFolder + "\\OutputTxt\\" + satuan.sName + "\\master.txt");
    zip.AddFile(CGlobalVar.CurrentMissionFolder + "\\OutputTxt\\" + satuan.sName + "\\slave.txt");
    zip.AddFile(CGlobalVar.CurrentMissionFolder + "\\OutputTxt\\" + satuan.sName + "\\sys_info.txt");
    zip.Save("E:\\" + satuan.sName + ".zip");
}
```

but when i try to Extract the file, the path also inside the zip file

```
Ops_V10\bin\Debug\data\CurrentMission\OutputTxt\BMS Server
```

the question is how to remove path my project inside the zip.

**example**

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddFile("archive.txt");
        zip.Save("E:\\archive.zip");
    }
```

when i extract the file archive zip, it must direct to archive.txt

without path `Ops_V10\bin\Debug\data\CurrentMission\OutputTxt\BMS Server`

i try [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405758/dotnetzip-how-to-extract-files-but-ignoring-the-path-in-the-zipfile) but i want to extract it manually.

how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddFile has a second parameter.. you pass an empty string to it dotnetzip will insert the item at the root path within the archive.

...AddFile(FullName, "")

Comment: it works, thanks, i dont know AddFile also have two arguments.